# Value error while using linear regression | ML

Tags: scikit-learn

With reference to the below screen, I received the error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

For reading purposes, i'm appending screen shot. Please advise where I have gone wrong. Thanks for your assistance.

My Code:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is often more helpful to post your code as markdown as opposed to as pictures. That way people can reproduce it to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have missing values in your DF (NaN) means no observations. You need to skip these values since linear regression cannot handle them. Looks like conversion of sqm failed. Check what the format is and try to get int or float from sqm column to avoid NaN.

If you want to skip NaNs read the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html